# cordova azure push notification custom backend

Tags: cordova, azure, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to work around the following:

- Azure push notification (WNS and GCM)
- Custom backend (more on that bellow)
- Win10 client (working fine so far)
- cordova client for Android/iOS (current pain point)

As opposed to most tutorials found on Azure documentation I want to use my own node backend to trigger notifications and not an Azure Mobile Service.

I have configured Azure push notification and I can send and receive notification on a W10 client using only Notification hub connection strings such as:

```
Endpoint=sb://<myns>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=<mykeyname>;SharedAccessKey=<mykey>
```

I can register my notification template and receive notifications on my W10 app.

I want now to do the same on a Cordova app. All the tutorials I have found so far rely on first connecting to an Azure Mobile Service and access the push service through its client.

What I am trying to do is register a custom notification template using an EndPoint=sb:// connection string so I can receive notifications on my Android device.

On my custom node backend, I use the Azure package and its createNotificationHubService method to send custom notifications.

Any pointers on how to register an Azure Notification Hub client without an Azure Mobile service backend would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I am heading towards Notification Hub REST Api with Typescript to complete the whole template registration without Azure Mobile App client.

This is my starting point:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530746.aspx

A.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You said you are not using Azure Mobile service, so you use `createNotificationHubService` method to send custom notifications. But what issue do you encounter when you use that method to send custom notifications?

Comment: I don't have any issue sending custom notification. My issue is registering a Cordova client without relying on creating a new Azure Mobile App client instance first and using its `client.push.register(...)` method

Comment: Does [this blog post](https://shellmonger.com/2016/05/23/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-24-push-with-tags/) help you?

Comment: Thanks @AaronChen-MSFT, however the post you share mentions `client.push.register(pns, data.registrationId, templates);` 
where the client object is an Azure Mobile App client instance `client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(azureBackend);` which is what I want to avoid
[sample Source code](https://github.com/adrianhall/30-days-of-zumo-v2/blob/day-24/blog-code/Client.Cordova/www/scripts/index.js)

Comment: @agu - were you able to achieve this? I also want to call my **Api App** in which I have configured **Notification Hub** from my Ionic-Cordova app but haven't been able to make it work. I tried using `client.push.register(...)` but it doesn't seem to work...nothing happens.